# If an object falls from a great height, such that the force of gravity is nonuniform, how much energy is dissipated by air resistance during the fall?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, astronomy, drag

We are also to assume that air resistance provides a small perturbation to the motion, which is largely determined by the force of gravity.

Suppose that air resistance is proportional to the square of the velocity.

I know that the change of energy is equal to the work done on the system, so
$$\Delta E = \int_{0}^t F_{air}\dot{x}dt' = k\int_0^t\dot{x}^3dt'=k\int_{x_0}^x\dot{x}'^2dx$$

However, this yields an integral I don't know how to calculate. I also don't know how the fact of $F_{air}$ being smaller than $F_g$ plays a factor. But I do know that I could solve for the velocity of the object at the surface of the planet it is crashing into, and just calculate the change in total energy of the system compared to what it normally would be.

So I figured I needed to solve the original differential equation.
$$\ddot{x} = G\frac{M}{x^2}-k\dot{x}^2$$
This has also not shown to be pleasant, and I am not sure how to use the "perturbative" idea to assist me.

I'm now at the point where I am attempting to solve the five less difficult related problems in order to better understand this. That is using both linear and quadratic drags for cases where the force of gravity is 0, uniform, and finally non-uniform.

Am I wasting my time by taking this approach, or is there a clever solution I don't see?

Comment: The assumption that air resistance scales with $v^2$ is not valid if you are looking at a range where $g$ is not constant. I.e, the earth atmosphere is about 30 km thick, hence $k$ in your equation would change more rapidly than $g$. A good model for $k$ would be $k=k_0 \exp{-x}$

Comment: @Bernhard I accept your point, but I have to work with the assumptions I was given.

Comment: Makes sense, and so does your approach. The equation you solve is non-linear (check the sign though), so I doubt if there is analytic solutions to that problem. I don't think linearising (o perturbation) will help you in this case. The latter only makes sense if you want to solve the problem over a small range of $x$. You can however use the solutions of the subproblems as upper or lower bound and  conclude at least something based on that.

Comment: I guess you need the exact solution. If not, than actually $F_\textrm{g}=F_\textrm{air}$ seems to be a good approximation, unless $k$ is (too) 'small'.

Comment: @fanyul I do indeed need the exact solution, if I can get it. $F_g = F_{air}$ is the limiting case though as $t\to\infty$, so it's not a good approximation.